# akka actor: Patterns.pipe for Either

Tags: scala, design-patterns, akka, actor

I have a method like this:

```
def myFuture: Future[Either[MyLeft, MyRight]] = Future {
.
.
.
}
```

If I want to pipe the result, I use:

```
Patterns.pipe(myFuture,ec).to(destinationActor)
```

But I want in case of Left , send result to one actor and in case of Right send result to another actor. pseudo code like this:

```
MyPatterns.eitherPipe(myFuture,ec).to(leftConsumerActor,rightConsumerActor)
```

Comment: Is there anything else you would like to see in the answer to this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code of akka itself is a good hint what should be done. Have a look at `akka.pattern.PipeToSupport`:

```
def pipeTo(recipient: ActorRef)(implicit sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Future[T] = {
  future andThen {
    case Success(r) ⇒ recipient ! r
    case Failure(f) ⇒ recipient ! Status.Failure(f)
  }
}
```

So we can basically reuse this approach for our case with dispatching of `Either`:

```
val result: Future[Either[Int, Throwable]] = Future.successful(Left(5))
result andThen {
  case Success(Left(value)) => leftActor ! value
  case Success(Right(exception)) => rightActor ! exception
  case Failure(exception) => println("Failure")
}
```

**Achieving desired DSL:**

We can try to achieve your DSL(**eitherPipe()** and **to(...)**) like this:

```
trait MyEitherPipeSupport extends PipeToSupport {

    final class PipeableEitherFuture[L, R](val future: Future[Either[L, R]])(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) {

      def to(leftRef: ActorRef, rightRef: ActorRef, exceptionRef: ActorRef) = future andThen {
        case Success(Left(value)) ⇒ leftRef ! value
        case Success(Right(exception)) ⇒ rightRef ! exception
        case Failure(exception) ⇒ exceptionRef ! Status.Failure(exception)
      }
    }

    implicit def eitherPipe[L, R](future: Future[Either[L, R]])(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext): PipeableEitherFuture[L, R] = new PipeableEitherFuture(future)

  }
```

Now in your actor you just mix `MyEitherPipeSupport` in and you can write like this:

```
    val result: Future[Either[Int, Throwable]] = Future.successful(Left(5))
    eitherPipe(result).to(left, right, anotherOne)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like this ?

```
myFuture onComplete {
   case Success(s) => s match {
      case Right(r) => rightConsumerActor ! r 
      case Left(l) =>  leftConsumerActor ! l
  }
   case Failure(f) => println("failure")
}
```